# How return forbidden in play framework 2 Java action composition

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have created new action composition and in some cases i need return forbidden how to do it correctly ?

```
public class VerboseAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
    Logger.debug(ctx.request().username());

    //return delegate.call(ctx);
    return forbidden();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a `Promise<SimpleResult>`.

```
return F.Promise.pure((SimpleResult) forbidden());
```